# How to make Mysql data provider present in data connection in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, xampp

I am new to this technology and I badly need help regarding to this Mysql Database (Mysql Data Provider). I am planning to use data binding for my navigation of student details in my xampp database but when I'm trying to create a dataset, there wasn't Mysql Database (Mysql Data Provider) available. I've tried almost all solutions I've saw in the internet but none of them works. Please help me. btw I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Xampp Mysql for the database. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, MySQL for visual studio isn't updated yet! it runs only on VS 2019 and lower, so you can't use it on VS 2022 at this moment.
But you can link your MySQL database with your C# project via Connect / Disconnect mode but not with Entity framework.